# Passing constructor parameters to initialize an object

Tags: java, constructor

I'm writing a java class that borrows elements of another class and need to pass three of the four parameters of the constructor to initialize the other class object. I'm lost as to how to initialize it, though. Any help is much appreciated. Here's what I have right now:

```
    private String name;
    private MyDate birthday;

    /**
     * Constructs a new Person object. 
     */
    public Person(String name, int month, int day, int year) {
        this.birthday = birthday(month, day, year);
        this.name = name;

    }
```

Comment: Looks like you want `this.birthday = new MyDate(month, day, year);` - that's how you call a constructor, after all. (As an aside, I would strongly encourage you to reorder those parameters to year, month, day - in both classes involved.)

Comment: I think I tried every combination but that one. lol Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will depend on whether or not the birthday class is connected by some means (extended or friended) or if the birthday.birthday field is publicly accessible.

For example, if you wanted to keep up with good practice. You could set up a
GetBirthday(); method inside of the birthday class and do the following.

```
private MyDate birthdate;


public Person(String name, int month, int day, int year) {
    birthday bDay = new birthday(month, day, year);
    this.birthdate = bDay.GetBirthday();
    this.name = name;

}
```

You could also create an inline function birthday() which calculates birthdays, but I would not advise doing it as such.

Comment: It's not clear to me that there needs to be a birthday class at all (which would certainly not be called `birthday`, and wouldn't have a method called `GetBirthday`, IMO) - see my comment. It seems to me that all which is required is a call to the `MyDate` constructor.